# Can selenium recognize aria-uuid as an ID for object recognition?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I recently recommended to my devs to add IDs to each element on the project I'm working to make automation more robust, they added in aria-uuid to each element. I cannot get anything to recognize these IDs! I'm wondering if it is even possible?

I'm using python/selenium.

I've tried identifying elements by ID, I've done CSS selectors and xpaths but they have had a history of breaking between new builds.

Relevant html:

```
input class="short ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-required" name="question_16" type="number" aria-uuid="question_16_input" ng-required="true" ng-min="0" ng-model="$ctrl.vault['question_16'].value"
```

```
def click_element_by_id(self, driver_init, id1, message1, delay1, halt):
  try:
      element = WebDriverWait(driver_init, delay1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, id1)))
      element.click()
  except TimeoutException:
      if halt:
          assert_that(True, message1).is_false()
      else:
          print(message1)
```

Each time I get the assertion/timeout error

Comment: Update the question with relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, **yes** you should have been able to recognize each individual elements with respect to their **`aria-uuid`** to be used with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) provided the generated **`aria-uuid`** were **static**.

As per the HTML you have shared the generated **`aria-uuid`** seems to be **dynamic**. So **`aria-uuid`** alone **won't help you**. In these cases you have to use the **`aria-uuid`** along with the other `attributes` to uniquely identify the elements. To identify this element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver_init, delay1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.short.ng-valid.ng-not-empty.ng-valid-min.ng-valid-required[aria-uuid$='_input'][name^='question_']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver_init, delay1).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='short ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-required' and contains(@aria-uuid, '_input')][starts-with(@name, 'question_')]"))).click()
  ```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

I was using CSS Selectors/xpaths before, but I had not considered using them in conjunction with the aria-uuids.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible with a CSS selector `[aria-uuid='question_16_input']`